# call a Java class from JSP which is located in another server

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In my application, I need to communicate between two servers. In the first server, my Java stand alone application deployed and this will call a war file which is deployed in a SSL secured server to communicate with Payment Gateway.

I am calling the war file from my Java application and I am getting some response from there. Next, I will pass the details and will open a browser from my Java stand alone application. After reaching the payment page, we lost the connection from the server , because there is no responce from the payment gateway. After the transaction, they will send the response as a URL, which is specified in my config file.

My question is, I ned to pass the response values from the URL to my Java stand alone application,

Please help me to find out a solution for this

Regards,

Joby Joseph

Comment: Check apache httpclient it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [RMI](http://www.java2all.com/1/5/22/114/Technology/RMI/RMI-Program/RMI-example) (Remote Method Invocation) protocol, you can try use [EJB](http://openejb.codehaus.org/hello-world.html) (Enterprise JavaBeans) its Java RMI as core implementation.

Another option is to use [JMX](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/jms_ch2/)

Comment: The problem is not to use RMI or EJB... I can connect all there two servers. But, after going the payment gateway page, there enxiting this method and I am getting the response from payment gateway as a JSP file. so, I need to send this response to my another server..